# Vaddin, необязательный параметр в url-ле,

Tags: java, frontend, vaadin

Например,

Если параметра в урле нет, то должны отобразиться все заказы всех клиентов менеджера(https://..../orders),

---

[image: class OrderList]

---

если параметр есть, все заказы клиента(https://..../orders/{clientId}).
например, [image: url с параметром]

Есть класс ManagerView отрисовывется в первую очередь,

---

[image: класс ManagerView]

---

class ManagerView.java

```
...............
    @Route(value = "")
    @RoutePrefix("manager")
    public class ManagerView extends AppLayout implements TokenListener {
    
        private final AuthService authService;

public ManagerView(AuthService authService) {
    this.authService = authService;
    this.authService.getToken(this);
}

private void createHeader() {
```

.....................................

```
 private void createDrawer() {
    RouterLink link1 = new RouterLink("Заказы", OrderList.class);
    link1.addClassName("link1");
    RouterLink link2 = new RouterLink("Клиенты", ClientList.class);
    link2.addClassName("link2");
    link1.setHighlightCondition(HighlightConditions.sameLocation());
    link2.setHighlightCondition(HighlightConditions.sameLocation());

    addToDrawer(new VerticalLayout(link1, link2));
}

    @Override
    public void execute(String token) {
        createHeader();
        createDrawer();
    }
}
```

И класс OrderList, отвечает за отрисовку таблицы, при клике на "Заказы".

class OrderList.java

```
...............
        @Route(value = "orders", layout = ManagerView.class)
        public class OrderList extends VerticalLayout implements TokenListener, HasUrlParameter<Long>{
        
            private Long parametrClientId;
        
            private final AuthService authService;
            private final OrderService orderService;

.................................
    @Override
    public void execute(String token) {
        createDrawer(token);
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameter(BeforeEvent beforeEvent, Long parametrClientId) {
        this.parametrClientId = parametrClientId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в классе OrderList, в методе setParametr, добавить аннотацию: @OptionalParameter

```
      @Override
    public void setParameter(BeforeEvent beforeEvent, @OptionalParameter Long parametrClientId) {
        this.parametrClientId = parametrClientId;
    }
}
```

https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.4.7/com/vaadin/flow/router/OptionalParameter.html